# Python & Pandas: Set a random value to a column, based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe look like this:

[image]

I want to set the `speed` into a uniform random value between 0,1, if the `dir` is 999 and if 'speed' is 0.

I do this:

```
df.loc[(df['dir'] == 999)&(df['speed'] == 0), 'speed'] = np.random.uniform(0,1)
```

But it turns out every speed is set into same value:

```
date
19800111    0.453046
19800111    0.453046
19800111    0.453046
19800111    0.453046
19800111    0.453046
19800111    0.453046
19800111    0.453046
19800111    0.453046
```

I'm not sure what I did is wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please dont use png, Users cant cut and paste data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "broadcasting" `np.random.uniform(0,1)` to all of the rows, meaning you're only calling `np.random.uniform(0,1)` once.  This is why you always see the same number.

You can update your dataframe based on your conditions like so:

```
In [46]: data = [{"dir":310, "speed":5.1}, {"dir":999, "speed":0}]

In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [48]: df
Out[48]: 
   dir  speed
0  310    5.1
1  999    0.0

In [49]: df.speed = df.apply(lambda x: np.random.uniform(0, 1) if x.speed == 0 and x.dir == 999 else x.speed, axis=1)

In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
   dir     speed
0  310  5.100000
1  999  0.948842
```

Comment: Do I need to put `df.loc[(df['dir'] == 999)&(df['speed'] == 0), 'speed'] =` before your code? This looks very long and strange....

Comment: The problem I'm asking that is `.loc[].apply` returns the correct value (ramdon value different from each other), but how should I set them into the `df`? Add that long `df.loc[(df['dir'] == 999)&(df['speed'] == 0), 'speed'] =`?

Comment: @cqcn1991 see the edit.  Not sure what looks strange to you.  Is it the  lambda?  It's just an anonymous function that apply calls for each element.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I forget about the `df.apply` syntax at all.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can specify the `size` parameter in the `uniform` function to be equal to the number of rows that you are trying to modify:

```
ind = (df['dir'] == 999) & (df['speed'] == 0)
df.loc[ind, 'speed'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = sum(ind))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['speed'] = np.where( (df['dir'] == 999) & (df['speed'] == 0),  np.random.uniform(0,1), df['speed'])
```

Comment: If the answer is right, please mark as correct. And dont forget to upvote